# Символы Unicode которых нет на клавиатуре

Tags: c#, unicode

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла такая проблема. Нужно напечатать в консоли символ "галочка" также известный как HEAVY CHECK MARK. Его код в юникоде '\u2714'. Однако когда я пишу такой код:

```
Console.WriteLine('\u2714');
```

То на экран выводится не галочка а знак вопроса. Тот же знак вопроса выводится и при любом другом подобном символе. При этом когда я вывожу этот код в консоли браузера (просто чтобы убедиться что это верный код) то получаю нужную мне галочку. Пробовал устанавливать кодировку

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // а также Unicode, UTF7, UTF32, Default и даже ASCII
```

но это не помогло. Можно ли как то решить эту проблему? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И не поможет. Для консоли кодировки недостаточно, ей нужно ещё, чтобы шрифт умел отображать ваш символ. Традиционно консольные шрифты в Windows поддерживают английскую часть Unicode и язык локали (например, русский), но не весь Unicode.

Если вам действительно нужен вывод символов, попробуйте найти более подходящий шрифт.

Если вам это нужно лишь в целях отладки, воспользуйтесь другими средствами (например, [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx)).

---

- [вот](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99795) Microsoft'овская статья из KB по этому же поводу
- [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/276994) обсуждение на StackOverflow, там по существу рекомендуют шрифты Lucida.